# How can I disable autoplay on this video in iframe?

Tags: html, video, iframe

I am trying to **disable to autoplay** on this video on my website. Here is the code I am using:

```
<div style="height: 450px;">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="400" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="//www.elocallink.tv/m/1.7a/pv_prd_ell_pop.php?pid=Q3aN4ww4A2&amp;videocid=N6N7Q7N4p61&amp;ismobile=false&amp;vversion=74&amp;ss=undefined&amp;mid=undefined&amp;forceap=undefined&amp;bpid=w4Qx4QN42" id="popframe" name="popframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" oallowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true" style="height:200%;width:100%"" type="text/html" width="700"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have tried placing my video into a video tag rather than an iFrame but that is not working with the source for some reason.

Does anyone have a simple solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried video tag like this? I read that you tried video tag, but I don't know how you use it.

```
<video src="https://vid.hellonetcdn.com/vid/ga/catoosacountychamberofcommerce/biz/gacato_20_auth_iwd_lrg_univ.mp4?e38745c27f40642d5060466095b4f9dc163cc39e4665f99234a90aab77a52f0a02345d798aa33466b24f29cfdee8f07048d9c752f9"></video>
```

I tried this code on jsbin, and is working if you right-click on video and click play: https://jsbin.com/vovahogeza/edit?html,output

UPDATE

With thumbnail/poster:

```
<video poster="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/150EA/production/_107005268_gettyimages-611696954.jpg" src="https://vid.hellonetcdn.com/vid/ga/catoosacountychamberofcommerce/biz/gacato_20_auth_iwd_lrg_univ.mp4?e38745c27f40642d5060466095b4f9dc163cc39e4665f99234a90aab77a52f0a02345d798aa33466b24f29cfdee8f07048d9c752f9"></video>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that might work. I think I was doing the video tag wrong the first time. Using your tag example I was able to make the video appear and not play.

Comment: Any tips on how to get a thumbnail to show before play instead of just a black screen?

Comment: Of course, with the poster attribute: https://jsbin.com/wovukujoxu/edit?html,output

I updated my answer to show the code too.

Comment: fantastic!!! You saved me! Thank you so much for all your help.